# Webstorm 10.0 Typescript compiler incorrect sourcemaps

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm, source-maps

I am trying to get my TypeScript sourcemaps right using the Webstorm 10.0 build-in compiler, so I can debug my js directly in my ts files.

Problem: sourcemaps don't have the right sources.

steps:

1) New Webstorm 10.0 project: "project"

2) 2 folders: project/src and project/build

3) index.ts in project/src

4.1) Webstorm -> preferences -> Languages & Frameworks -> TypeScript

```
+ Enable TypeScript Compiler
+ Use output path: build/$FileDirRelativeToProjectRoot$
```

=> This generates .js and .js.map files in build/src/, but sources are incorrect:

```
"sources":["index.ts"]
```

I tried nearly everything, including using the --sourceRoot and --sourceMap compiler options.

Any clear directive on how one would need to configure the compiler with a structure like this?

edit: filed as a bug: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-16049

Comment: Could it potentially be a bug, you might want to file a report at youtrack.jetbrains.com

Comment: I thought so to, but wanted to ask here first. I'll file an issue, thanks.

Comment: I experience this exact same thing. Until this issue is resolved there seems to be no way to generate sourcemaps correctly unless your .js and .ts files are in the same directory.